# Looping Over a Set of Files

Tags: r, loops

I cooked up some code that is supposed to find all my .txt files (they're outputs of ODE simulations), open them all up as data frames with "read.table" and then perform some calculations on them.

```
files <- list.files(path="/Users/redheadmammoth/Desktop/Ultimate_Aging_F2016",
                pattern=".txt",full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(files, read.table)
tuse <- seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.1)

for(files in ldf)
  findR <- function(r){
    with(files,(sum(exp(-r*age)*fecund*surv*0.1)-1)^2)
    }
    {
        R0 <- with(files,(sum(fecund*surv*age)))
        GenTime <- with(files,(sum(tuse*fecund*surv*0.1))/R0)
        r <- optimize(f=findR,seq(-5,5,.0001),tol=0.00000001)$minimum
        RV <- with(files,(exp(r*tuse)/surv)*(exp(-r*tuse)*(fecund*surv))) 

plot(log(surv) ~ age,files,type="l")
tmp.lm <- lm(log(surv) ~ age + I(age^2),files) #Fit log surv to a quadratic
lines(files$age,predict(tmp.lm),col="red")
}
```

However, the problem is that it seems to only be performing the calculations contained in my "for" loop on one file, rather than all of them. I'd like it to perform the calculations on all of my files, then save all the files together as one big data frame so I can access the results of any particular set of my simulations. I suspect the error is that I'm not indexing the files correctly in order to loop over all of them.

Comment: Here's the answer. The was an anonymous/serial downvote on it so I deleted it. http://pastebin.com/kpAWihvU

Comment: Your `lapply()` and `for()` can be combined. Please show desired result? Do you want to save dataframes **and** plot a linear model? Additionally are the *R0*, *GenTime*, *r*, and *RV* to be new columns in each dataframe?

Comment: Right. Yeah, I would like it to calculate those life-history parameters (R0 etc.) and then save them as a new column on each data frame. And I would like to save each data frame and plot a linear model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using plyr::ldply() for this. It takes a list (in your case your list of files) and performs the same function on them and then returns a data frame.

The main thing to remember to do is create a column for the ID of each file you read in so you know which data comes from which file. The simplest way to do this is just to call it the file name and then you can edit it from there.

If you have additional arguments in your function they go after the function you want to use in ldply.

```
        # create file list
        files <- list.files(path="/Users/redheadmammoth/Desktop/Ultimate_Aging_F2016",
                            pattern=".txt",full.names=TRUE)
        tuse <- seq(from=0,to=100,by=0.1)

        load_and_edit <- function(file, tuse){
            temp <- read.table(file)

            # here put all your calculations you want to do on each file
            temp$R0 <- sum(temp$fecund*temp$surv*temp*age)

            # make a column for each file name so you know which data comes from which file
            temp$id <- file

            return(temp)
           }


        new_data <- plyr::ldply(list.files, load_and_edit, tuse)
```

This is the easiest way I have found to read in and wrangle multiple files in batch.

You can then plot each one really easily.

Comment: The solution I ended up happening on is rather similar to yours! And thank you for such a quick response... It plots all 118 experiment outcomes right handily after calculating everything too. Now just let me figure out how to upvote your answer ;)